# Please explain the use of ':' and a trailing ',' in this struct initialization C code

Tags: c, linux, uclinux

```
static struct file_operations memory_fops = {
    open:       memory_open,    /* just a selector for the real open */
};
```

this is from mem.c file in uclinux

Comment: Please use proper formatting for code samples, it makes helping you a lot easier.  Best,

Answer (score 6):

That's GNU-style initialization syntax; the `open` member is initialized to `memory_open`, the rest is left uninitialized.  C99 uses a different syntax (`.open = memory_open`).

Comment: Right.  It's worth noting that this is probably really old code: the GCC docs say the old GNU style syntax is "obsolete since GCC 2.5", which was released in 1993.  :-)

Comment: Are you sure about "left uninitialized" part? Normally in C it is all-or-nothing, i.e. if at least *something* is initialized, then everything else is *zero-initialized*. That's how it works in C99 with the new syntax. Of course, a GCC-specific extension can behave differently.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I would expect old-style behavior with the old-style initializer:  globals are initialized to 0, `auto` (stack) variables will be whatever trash was using that memory space before.

Comment: Well, once again, with aggregate initializers C has always followed that policy very strictly: if some struct (or array)  object is partially initialized by the user, then the rest is zero-initialized. The only way to see "trash" in a variable is not to initialize it at all. Not even a part of it.

Comment: ... and that *is* old-style behavior, BTW.

Answer (score 6):

In C the optional trailing comma was allowed in brace-enclosed initializers since the beginning of time. It is there so that you can use uniform comma placement in initializers like

```
struct SomeStructType s = {
  value1,
  value2,
  value3,
};
```

This makes it easier, for example, to rearrange the initializers in the list, should such a need arise. Whether you want to use it or not is a matter of personal preference.

As for the `:` syntax, it is a GCC-specific extension as @geekosaur already explained. The corresponding functionality was standardized in C99 with a different syntax.

Comment: So the beginning of time for you is C99 ? interesting :) I think trailing commas (for initializers and `enum`) have been added then.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: No. In C99 trailing commas became allowed in *enums* specifically. And one of the reasons they were added was to remove the ages-old inconsistency between enums and brace-enclosed initializers. In the latter the trailing  comma was allowed since the beginning of time, as I said above (at least since C89/90), while in enums the trailing comma was illegal before C99.

Comment: right. I am convinced that I had read that somewhere, but searching around on the web didn't bring up anything, my bad.

Comment: It also makes code generation routines easier (like some sort of utility tool that parses some data file and turns it into C source) as it removes the need to check if a comma needs inserting or not.